# Activity gone after launching from icon

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Flow:
 - Activity1
 - Start Activity2 (launchmode = singleInstance)
 - Close the app
 - Open app from app icon
 - Activity2 is not visible!

What can the the problem of this?
If i reopen the app from last used apps, the activity is visible (good).

Activity1 = used for login (only shown if app is destroyed / never opened)

Activity2 = where all the Fragments goes into. So this Activity must be shown if user open's app again (when it's closed).

Comment: what you want to achive

Comment: u want like the first activity should be shown only once ie) the first execution after the install right?

Comment: If the user wants to open the app again with the launcher icon, Activity2 must be back visible. It works without launchmode=singleInstance. But with the launchmode, the activity isn't visible

Comment: use shared preferernce